# How do I integrate Snipcart into Wagtail the right way?

Tags: wagtail

I’m following the Snipcart Wagtail tutorial https://snipcart.com/blog/django-ecommerce-tutorial-wagtail-cms but having difficulty creating the shop page as a separate app/model to the home page.

The tutorial overrides the home page context and adds the product data into the home page class’s products context variable. This doesn’t seem like the right way to do it and I’d rather have the shop on it’s own page and products in a 'shop' model rather than a 'home' model.